# Mix useEffect and Firebase's onValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When working with `Firebase` and `React`, in order to fetch data based on state changes or on inner database changes (from another user for example), I often rely on pieces of code like this one:

```
    useEffect(() => {

    const getGamesInSelectedGroup = () => {

        if (!state.currentGroup) {
            return
        }

        const db = getDatabase();
        const resp = ref(db, `/games/${state.currentGroup.name}`);

        onValue(resp, (snap) => {
            if (snap.exists()) {
                const data = snap.val()
                const games = Object.keys(data).map(k => ({id: k, group: state.currentGroup.name, ...data[k]}))

                setState((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    games: games,
                    isLoaded: true,
                }));
                return

            }
            setState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                games: null,
                isLoaded: true,
            }));
            toast.warning("no data for " + state.currentGroup.name)

        })
    }

    getGamesInSelectedGroup();

}, [state.currentGroup])
```

However, I am wondering if, whenever `state.currentGroup` changes, a new listener to `/games/${state.currentGroup.name}` is created? If so, is there a mean to unsubscribe to previous listener before creating a new one?

I have thinking about replacing `onValue` by a `get` call, still conditioned on `state.currentGroup` and using `onValue` outside `useEffect`to reflect "inner" database change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than nest everything in your `getGamesInSelectedGroup` function (which is the pattern you would use for Promise-based APIs), just call it in the body of the `useEffect` to make managing the listener simpler:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.currentGroup) {
        return
    }

    const db = getDatabase();
    const resp = ref(db, `/games/${state.currentGroup.name}`);

    return onValue(resp, (snap) => { // <--- return the unsubscriber!
        if (snap.exists()) {
            const data = snap.val()
            const games = Object.keys(data)
                 .map(k => ({
                     id: k,
                     group: state.currentGroup.name,
                     ...data[k]
                 }));

            setState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                games, // you can use this instead of "games: games"
                isLoaded: true,
            }));
            return
        }
        setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            games: null,
            isLoaded: true,
        }));
        toast.warning("no data for " + state.currentGroup.name)
    });
}, [state.currentGroup])
```

I would also recommend using a "snapshot to array of children" function rather than using `Object.keys(snapshot.val())` to maintain the sort order from the query (it would be ignored using the code as-is). Unfortunately, at the time of writing, there is no equivalent of Firestore's [`QuerySnapshot#docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotdocs) for the RTDB just yet. But it's pretty easy to make our own:

```
// returns array of DataSnapshot objects under this DataSnapshot
// put this outside of your component, like in a common function library file
const getSnapshotChildren = (snapshot) => {
    const children = [];
    // note: the curly braces on the next line are important! If the
    // callback returns a truthy value, forEach will stop iterating
    snapshot.forEach(child => { children.push(child) })
    return children;
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.currentGroup) {
        return
    }

    const db = getDatabase();
    const resp = ref(db, `/games/${state.currentGroup.name}`);

    return onValue(resp, (snap) => { // <--- return the unsubscriber!
        if (snap.exists()) {
            const games = getSnapshotChildren(snap)
                 .map(child => ({
                     id: child.key,
                     group: state.currentGroup.name,
                     ...child.val()
                 }));

            setState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                games, // you can use this instead of "games: games"
                isLoaded: true,
            }));
            return
        }
        setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            games: null,
            isLoaded: true,
        }));
        toast.warning("no data for " + state.currentGroup.name)
    });
}, [state.currentGroup])
```

Comment: Thus, now,  by returning the unsubscriber, am I sure that a single listener will be managed at any time?

Comment: @floflo29 you will have at most one active listener. The above code has not included the error listener. You can refer to the API Reference for details for that.

Comment: ok, and you confirm that, with my previous, code multiple listeners where instantiated (i.e. a new one whenever useEffect is called)?

Comment: @floflo29 Yes, in your previous code, on every render/change of state, you would attach a new listener, but because you were not using the unsubscribe function to clean up the old listener, you would be stacking them on top of each other.