# React Native - Data retrieve from Realtime database Firebase not updated automatically in app when change

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

The problem is my apps did not automatically update the data from the realtime database when I change the data (number).

Only when I refresh the apps with my VS Code, the data will change in my apps.

But the **`console.log`** work find when the data is change in the realtime database.

I am still new in react native. Can anyone help to find the problem?

I have included my coding and the database.

[image]

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import Icons from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import { FlatGrid } from "react-native-super-grid";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";

class DashScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          statusName: "Heart Rate",
          number: "",
          icon: "heartbeat",
          color: "#4a90e2",
          satuan: " BPM",
          percentage: 50,
        },
        {
          statusName: "Temperature",
          number: 35,
          icon: "temperature-low",
          color: "#4a90e2",
          satuan: " Celcius",
          percentage: 80,
        },
        {
          statusName: "Blood Pressure",
          number: 80,
          icon: "egg",
          color: "#4a90e2",
          satuan: " mm Hg",
          percentage: 30,
        },
      ],
    };

    const database = getDatabase();
    const db = database;
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "raspberrypi/" + "" + "/Oxygen");
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
      this.state.items[0].number = snapshot.val();
      console.log("On value:", this.state.items[0]);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <LinearGradient
          colors={["#525269", "#2f3963"]}
          style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 30 }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                marginLeft: 30,
                marginTop: 10,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: "#625476",
                paddingBottom: 20,
                paddingTop: 30,
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "#FFFFFF",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: 22,
                }}
              >
                Dashboard
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 0.2,
                borderBottomWidth: 3,
                borderBottomColor: "#FFFFFF",
                marginRight: 40,
              }}
            />
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
                marginTop: 20,
              }}
            >
              <Icons
                name="sign-out-alt"
                size={30}
                color="white"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
              />
            </View>
          </View>

          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              marginHorizontal: 30,
              marginTop: 30,
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text style={{ color: "#FFFFFF", fontSize: 18 }}>October</Text>
              <Text style={{ color: "#985da3" }}>2015</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <FlatGrid
            itemDimension={140}
            data={this.state.items}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            spacing={20}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#5a537a",
                  borderRadius: 15,
                  padding: 10,
                  height: 140,
                }}
              >
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: item.color,
                      paddingVertical: 3,
                      borderRadius: 50,
                      width: `${item.percentage}%`,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: "#FFFFFF",
                      fontSize: 18,
                      marginTop: 20,
                      marginLeft: 10,
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.statusName}
                  </Text>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 24,
                      color: "#FFFFFF",
                      marginLeft: 10,
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      marginTop: 8,
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.number}
                    <Text style={{ fontsize: 18, color: "#aca8bc" }}>
                      {item.satuan}
                    </Text>
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View
                  style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "flex-end" }}
                >
                  <Icons name={item.icon} size={30} color="#a9a8bb" />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </LinearGradient>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DashScreen;
```

Firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCrkFOwnU_Og72ebfoefXt0Qij9BrCajJk",
  authDomain: "fir-auth-1a54a.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL:
    "https://fir-auth-1a54a-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "fir-auth-1a54a",
  storageBucket: "fir-auth-1a54a.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1088108013165",
  appId: "1:1088108013165:web:e76831d5f9e88721400164",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
const database = getDatabase(app);
const db = getFirestore();

export default app;
```

Comment: instead of updating the values in your state, you should call this.setState so that it forces the component to rerender. Also, the answer mentioning taking a hook base approach isnt a bad idea. [react-fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactfire) gives you lots of hooks if you are concern about making your own hooks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refactor your code to use hooks structure then your code will look something like this:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

...

const [myData, setMyData] = useState<MyDataType>({
  items: [{
    statusName: 'Heart Rate',
    number: '',
    icon: 'heartbeat',
    color: '#4a90e2',
    satuan: ' BPM',
    percentage: 50,
  }]
})

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Value changed', myData.items[0])
},[myData])

...

onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.val();
  setMyData(currentValue => {
    const {items} = currentValue
    const newItem = items[0]
    newItem.number = snapshot.val()
    
    return {
      ..currentValue,
      items
    }
  })
})


return (<div>
  .....
</div>)
```

Maybe you should set an event listener in `onValue` event using `useEffect`, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008942/mix-useeffect-and-firebases-onvalue)

Hope this helps you

Comment: useEffect cannot be use in class component if i not mistaken. So do I need to get rid of the class component?

Comment: in my opinion hooks components are easer to work with and it's a newer and modern syntax (even [react docs](https://react.dev/learn) are using it). It's easy to refactor using it.
But if you doesn't want, maybe you should look into [componentdidupdate](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your opinion, I will change my coding to hooks components. Btw if I want to fetch multiple data from realtime database, how to edit the coding you just gave me?

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/refactor-hfukmv?file=/DashScreen.tsx)'s a quick refactor, maybe there's something you'll need to modify or fix (because I have not installed all dependencies) but this gives you a north

Comment: [react-fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactfire) have lots of premade firebase hooks built